# Bootstrap 4 carousel with fade effect without embed-responsive class

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to do a carousel with fade effect. I found a way on stackoverflow but it adds classes `embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9` `embed-responsive-item`. And with them it looks awful on mobile view. If I remove them carousel breaks and I see white background and if I scroll down I can see my images. Maybe there is a better way to do fade effect?

```css
$dark-overlay: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .carousel-item {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity ease-out .7s;
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .carousel-item.active {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.carousel-item:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: $dark-overlay;
}

.carousel-caption {
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  bottom: initial;
  top:50%;
}

.carousel-image-1 {
  background: url('../images/miami1.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
}

.carousel-image-2 {
  background: url('../images/miami2.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
}

.carousel-image-3 {
  background: url('../images/miami3.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
   <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-image-1 embed-responsive-item">
                <div class="carousel-caption text-right">
                    <h1 class="display-3">Sveiki</h1>
                    <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor enim ex
                        exercitationem laboriosam nihil numquam tempora, vitae voluptates. Dolores, maxime!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-image-2 embed-responsive-item active">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1 class="display-3">Miami</h1>
                    <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor enim ex
                        exercitationem laboriosam nihil.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sužinok daugiau</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item carousel-image-3 embed-responsive-item">
                <div class="carousel-caption text-right">
                    <h1 class="display-3">Sveiki</h1>
                    <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor enim ex
                        exercitationem laboriosam nihil numquam tempora, vitae voluptates. Dolores, maxime!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" class="carousel-control-prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" class="carousel-control-next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: By awful you mean that your `.carousel-caption` goes out of the boundaries of the carousel itself?

Comment: Yeah. That's what happening

Comment: Actually this has nothing to do with the `.embed-responsive` classes, but it is happening because of the `.carousel-caption` has `position: absolute` by default. Thus it does not respect the size of it's parent. Therefore even the Bootstrap docs suggests to hide the caption on smaller screens. …or you could have a `min-height` on `.carousel-item` and also decrease the font size for mobiles of the caption as well.